# How to decrypt form data encoded using multiform/form-data in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, post

I was working on a project and came across an issue

I needed to get a file uploaded from client so i used

```
<form action='upload.jsp' method='post' enctype='multiform/form-data'>
```

There was no problem till now because only the file was being uploaded and the data was parsed by upload.jsp (found on internet)

But when I added some more input elements to the form, like date and number, and access it on the other page, I'm getting null. How can i decode these input form elements sent with the file?

Comment: Sigh, `enctype` is **encoding** type. This has nothing to do with encryption.

Comment: I'm not asking how to upload a file, i know how to upload a file. I want to know how to decode other form elements

Comment: Which the answer to that question demonstrates.

Comment: @darknight Do you want to receive the form elements on server side ? And which library you use for file upload ?

Comment: @san krish I'm using apache-commons library, and yes i want to recieve the form elements on the server side

Comment: Try posting the new question with the code , where you need the help . will assist you